# User named 'daemon' has a process 'urlexceptiond' in OS X process list

Tags: macos, operating-systems

What is this process called `urlexceptiond` in OS X (*latest version*)?

The user is `daemon` and I wonder if it could be malware ?

Comment: The only Google hit I can see on that process would tell me it's part of F-Secure.

Comment: Ok.. I go back under my rock... I was just running a scan with F-Secure... LOL! Sorry about this question!

Comment: No, it's a valid question & google had only one hit for 'urlexceptiond' which was an Etre Check post on github. It was listed in the whitelist section, as com.f-secure.urlexceptiond.plist

Comment: First to check would be the path of the running executable either with `ps` oe `find`.

Answer (score 0):

As Alex has already said, a daemon is a background process, traditionally ending in the letter d.

In this particular case, it's part of `F-Secure Antivirus`, though I can't tie down exactly what it does it's safe to assume it's not malicious.

The full name of the file responsible is `com.f-secure.urlexceptiond.plist`

Answer (score -1):

A daemon is...

> ... a computer program that runs as a background process, rather than being under the direct control of an interactive user. Traditionally, the process names of a daemon end with the letter d, for clarification that the process is, in fact, a daemon, and for differentiation between a daemon and a normal computer program

So no, it's not malware